# Drag view while animating

Tags: android, animation, view, drag

I have a view that implements onTouchListener for dragging. 
Dragging event works perfectly. Now the problem is, that view is being animated, it has a random movement around screen and user has to pick it and drag it. View animates perfectly with `ObjectAnimator` but when you pick it and move it. Suddenly changes it's position to another. So What i think is that `ObjectAnimator` is moving object but it's not changing it's position because when you drag it, it goes  to it's original position first and then it gets dragged. Do I explain myself?

Comment: Yes, you should explain.

Comment: There's a view moving around screen (using ObjectAnimator) I want to make it draggable but when i drag it, it doesnt move from last position (changed by ObjectAnimator) it moves from original position (before ObjectAnimator makes effect)